# Can I be warned when I used a generator function by accident

Tags: python, function, generator, language-features

I was working with generator functions and private functions of a class. I am wondering

1. Why when yielding (which in my one case was by accident) in __someFunc that this function just appears not to be called from within __someGenerator. Also what is the terminology I want to use when referring to these aspects of the language?
2. Can the python interpreter warn of such instances?

Below is an example snippet of my scenario.

```
class someClass():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    #Copy and paste mistake where yield ended up in a regular function
    def __someFunc(self):
        print "hello"
        #yield True #if yielding in this function it isn't called

    def __someGenerator (self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.__someFunc()
            yield True
        yield False

    def someMethod(self):
        func = self.__someGenerator()
        while func.next():
            print "next"

sc = someClass()
sc.someMethod()
```

I got burned on this and spent some time trying to figure out why a function just wasn't getting called. I finally discovered I was yielding in function I didn't want to in.

Comment: Orthogonal Python suggestion: The leading double underscores are unnecessary, just use a single leading underscore and Python coders recognize that it's not part of the interface by gentleman's privacy.

Comment: How did you NOT know you had a yield statement?  Did someone else edit your code and you did an SVN up and got surprised by the update?  What was the scenario that lead to a function being a generator instead of an ordinary method.

Comment: @S.Lott: Copy/paste, as his comment mentions. I've always found copy/pastes of code to cause more headaches than they solve, but I know a lot of people find them useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer the first of your questions.

A regular function, when called like this:

```
val = func()
```

executes its inside statements until it ends or a `return` statement is reached. Then the return value of the function is assigned to `val`.

If a compiler recognizes the function to actually be a generator and not a regular function (it does that by looking for `yield` statements inside the function -- if there's at least one, it's a generator), the scenario when calling it the same way as above has different consequences. Upon calling `func()`, *no code inside the function is executed*, and a special `<generator>` value is assigned to `val`. Then, the first time you call `val.next()`, the actual statements of `func` are being executed until a `yield` or `return` is encountered, upon which the execution of the function stops, value yielded is returned and generator waits for another call to `val.next()`.

That's why, in your example, function `__someFunc` didn't print "hello" -- its statements were not executed, because you haven't called `self.__someFunc().next()`, but only `self.__someFunc()`.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure there's no built-in warning mechanism for programming errors like yours.

Answer (score 6):

A "generator" isn't so much a language feature, as a name for functions that "yield."  Yielding is pretty much always legal.  There's not really any way for Python to know that you didn't "mean" to yield from some function.

This PEP http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/ talks about generators, and may help you understand the background better.

I sympathize with your experience, but compilers can't figure out what you "meant for them to do", only what you actually told them to do.

Comment: I did finally come across pep 255. It does go into some detail. the section "Specification: Return" describes some of this well. Also other parts of the pep mention or discuss issues with try/catch and using yield. I did remain hopeful that python interpreter might emit warnings (with appropriate flags perhaps); even gcc will warn you about things you said but might not have meant.

Comment: It is true that some native compilers can check for common sense problems, and occasionally for "you did X but you probably meant Y", but there are very few occasions when that is true, and they are generally quite specific (like order of operations in an expression or an if-test.)  But higher-level, "I didn't mean to return from this function yet, or I didn't mean to return in this way" are still  way beyond any compilers I'm aware of.  Out of curiosity, what hint do you think the compiler might have had that you were doing the wrong thing?

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't know whether you want to create a generator object for later iteration or call a function.  But python isn't your only tool for seeing what's going on with your code.  If you're using an editor or IDE that allows customized syntax highlighting, you can tell it to give the yield keyword a different color, or even a bright background, which will help you find your errors more quickly, at least.  In vim, for example, you might do:

```
:syntax keyword Yield yield
:highlight yield ctermbg=yellow guibg=yellow ctermfg=blue guifg=blue
```

Those are horrendous colors, by the way.  I recommend picking something better.  Another option, if your editor or IDE won't cooperate, is to set up a custom rule in a code checker like pylint.  An example from pylint's source tarball:

```
from pylint.interfaces import IRawChecker
from pylint.checkers import BaseChecker

class MyRawChecker(BaseChecker):
    """check for line continuations with '\' instead of using triple
    quoted string or parenthesis
    """

    __implements__ = IRawChecker

    name = 'custom_raw'
    msgs = {'W9901': ('use \\ for line continuation',
                     ('Used when a \\ is used for a line continuation instead'
                      ' of using triple quoted string or parenthesis.')),
           }
    options = ()

    def process_module(self, stream):
        """process a module

        the module's content is accessible via the stream object
        """
        for (lineno, line) in enumerate(stream):
            if line.rstrip().endswith('\\'):
                self.add_message('W9901', line=lineno)


def register(linter):
    """required method to auto register this checker"""
    linter.register_checker(MyRawChecker(linter))
```

The pylint manual is available here: http://www.logilab.org/card/pylint_manual
And vim's syntax documentation is here: http://www.vim.org/htmldoc/syntax.html

Answer (score 1):

Because the `return` keyword is applicable in both generator functions and regular functions, there's nothing you could possibly check (as @Christopher mentions). The `return` keyword in a generator indicates that a StopIteration exception should be raised.

If you try to `return` with a value from within a generator (which doesn't make sense, since `return` just means "stop iteration"), the compiler will complain at compile-time -- this may catch some copy-and-paste mistakes:

```
>>> def foo():
...     yield 12
...     return 15
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 3
SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator
```

I personally just advise against copy and paste programming. :-)

From the PEP:

> Note that return means "I'm done, and have nothing interesting to
>   return", for both generator functions and non-generator functions.

Answer (score 0):

We do this.

Generators have names with "generate" or "gen" in their name.  It will have a yield statement in the body.  Pretty easy to check visually, since no method is much over 20 lines of code.

Other methods don't have "gen" in their name.

Also, we do not every use `__` (double underscore) names under any circumstances.  32,000 lines of code.  Non `__` names.

The "generator vs. non-generator" method function is entirely a design question.  What did the programmer "intend" to happen.  The compiler can't easily validate your intent, it can only validate what you actually typed.